# Karma vs Protractor, Unit test vs. e2e test

Tags: javascript, angularjs, unit-testing, protractor, karma-jasmine

Could someone explain to me why I need both Protractor and Karma. At a quick glance it seems to me that they are doing the same thing. I understand Karma is for unit tests and Protractor is for e2e test.

- What is the main difference between 2 types of test?
- Why don't we use the same runner/framework for both purposes?
- Is there any specific reason to use both frameworks?

I understand both can use (and in most examples using) Jasmine framework to describe the tests.

Answer (score 6):

A unit test, by definition, tests a single unit of code, in isolation. Testing a controller, in isolation of the services it uses, or testing a service, in isolation of the backend REST server it sends requests to, is a good idea, and makes tests really fast, but having all these tests doesn't guarantee that, when everything is assembled together and really talks to a backend, the application runs as expected.

E2e tests test the application as a whole. They are the equivalent of a human tester sitting in front of a browser and using the application to see if it works as expected. Protractor is a layer on top of Selenium, which allows using a browser programmatically, i.e. write instructions to click on a link, fill in a form, submit it, as a human would do.

Comment: Thank you @JBNizet! This answers the first point from my question.

Comment: It actually answers them all, if you think a little.

Comment: I am looking forward to understand it. All examples of protractor test I've seen are pretty much like click here and there. In my opinion that does not make it different from Karma, I can do all that in Karma. If the difference is only in the way of using the tool, in that case we wouldn't need both tools. It would just add to the complexity.
I am looking for the real difference between these tools, and the reason why we need both. Is it the way of compilation, or session maintenance or anything like that?

Comment: No. In Karma, you create **unit** tests, testing **one** component, and mocking its dependencies. The test is executed inside the browser thanks to karma. No request goes to the backend. You test the logic and the view of one component. You can also unit-test a pipe, a service, or anything else. In protractor, the test is executed by NodeJS, not by the browser, and it tests the application as a whole, not just one component, by driving a browser as a user would do.

Comment: It's basically the difference between testing that a gas pump, or a circuit breaker, works (unit test) and testing that a car (which contains a gas pump, several circuit breakers, and many other things)  works (e2e test).